# Issue with CreatePassengerNameRecord API

Tags: php, json, sabre

I'm passing the correct `Amountspecified` value (603.53) to CreatePNR API but as response I'm getting below error. I'm attaching the `AirPrice` array which I have received from the `CreatePassengerNameRecord` API response.

```json
{
            "type": "BusinessLogic",
            "timeStamp": "2024-02-29T08:52:02.818Z",
            "SystemSpecificResults": [
              {
                "Message": [
                  {
                    "code": "WARN.SP.BUSINESS_ERROR",
                    "content": "EnhancedAirBookRQ: Price comparison AmountReturned \"603.53\" is over the specified limit for .../OTA_AirPriceRQ[1]/PriceComparison"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
```

```json
"AirPrice": [
        {
          "PriceComparison": {
            "AmountReturned": "603.53",
            "AmountSpecified": "603.52999999999997"
          },
         
        }
      ]
```

Anyone know that why `Amountspecified` value displays as decimal value in PNR response?

[image]

Comment: First thing first, check the API documentation. `CreatePassengerNameRecord` I guess you need to mass name or something?

Comment: Looks like you are dealing with a case of the inherent imprecision of float values here. You are only telling us that you were "passing it correctly" - but you have shown us no relevant code, so we can't know what you are actually doing. Maybe this value should rather be passed as a string value, than a number.

Comment: Hello @CBroe, I'm going to attach PNR request. Could you please check and let me know if I'm passing any wrong details?

Comment: You are passing it as a numeric value, try passing it as a string instead.

Comment: "AmountReturned": "603.53",
            "AmountSpecified": "603.52999999999997" , it sure does look like a string with " " around